# Changing PHP 5.4 code to PHP 5.3 to avoid syntax error

Tags: php

How do I change the following two codes so that they can be used in php 5.3

**first**

```
return [
    'Authorization: key=' . $this->apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];
```

**second**

```
$fields = [
    'registration_ids' => is_string($regIds) ? [$regIds] : $regIds,
    'data' => is_string($data) ?
         [
            'message' => $data,
            'title' => $title,
            'key' => $key
          ] : $data,
    ];
```

Comment: don't use [], use array(...) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware that it was legal in 5.5 to initialise arrays with just the `[]` brackets. Are you sure that your code does not run in 5.3 as it is?

If the issue is the array initialisation (cause the rest of the code seems quite fine), you could try with using `... array ( /**/ )` instead of `... [ /**/ ]`.
IE:

```
return array(
  'Authorization: key=' . $this->apiKey,
  'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

Comment: `[]` array notation was introduced in 5.4

Comment: yeah php 5.5 have lots of new features. whats your solution for second code?

Comment: @rishal Practically the same, `... 'registration_ids' => is_string($regIds) ? array($regIds) : $regIds, ...`.

Comment: @rishal the same - replace `[ /*whatever*/ ]` with `array( /*whatever*/ )`. Can't be too hard to grasp...